# iOS AlertView above YTPlayerView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller, ytplayerview

I have YTPlayerView on my viewController. If i create UIAlertController and show it by method `self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)` , alert will be shown under player view. How can i show alertView above all views on my viewController?

Here the code that i use now:

```
let title = "test alert message" let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(‌​alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: use appdelegate window instance or YTPlayerView  instance to present alert , it will come on top

Comment: Not work for me

Comment: what error you are getting ?. Please post detailed  are you showing alert from Viewcontroller

Comment: `let title = "test alert message"
let alert = UIAlertController(title:  title, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)`
Here the code that i use.
I not get any errors - but alert not shown above player view.

Comment: Post it in question